# Add some model reference to an existing model

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have created a module that serves my own authentication and users system. It's a universal module that I use in different applications. In this module a `User` model is described, like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    email = db.EmailProperty()
    password = db.StringProperty()
    role = db.StringProperty(default=roles.USER)
```

In any single application where I use this module, I'd like to create an extra model that describes additional fields that are specific for this application like this:

```
 class UserProfile(db.Model):
        first_name = db.StringProperty()
        last_name = db.StringProperty()
        company = db.StringProperty()
```

And I need to attach `UserProfile` model to `User` model inside my newly made application. How do I do that without having to modify the code inside the module that is common for all applications?

Comment: Do you mean two different applications in appengine ? I mean the one which we create inside appengine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had a users module that I imported accross several projects I would treat this shared module just as a *base* to build my apps on.

So you might have a `baseuser.py` module containing:

```
class UserModel(db.Model):
    email = db.EmailProperty()
    password = db.StringProperty()
    role = db.StringProperty(default=roles.USER)
```

Then in each GAE project you would have:

```
from baseuser import UserModel

class User(UserModel):
    first_name = db.StringProperty()
    last_name = db.StringProperty()
    company = db.StringProperty()
```

You would then be free to extend your User models per app, and keep all the shared logic in one place.

Answer (score 1):

So within any single application, this is presumably a one-to-one relationship. It's thus arbitrary where you store the reference. You can simply modify your UserProfile model to reference the User:

```
class UserProfile(db.Model):
        user = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
        first_name = db.StringProperty()
        last_name = db.StringProperty()
        company = db.StringProperty()
```

Then, in the controller:

```
user = User.filter('email =', email).get()
profile = UserProfile.filter('user =', user).get()
```

Alternately, if you wanted the reference to live on the User object but not break applications that don't support a profile, you could do this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    email = db.EmailProperty()
    password = db.StringProperty()
    role = db.StringProperty(default=roles.USER)
    profile = db.ReferenceProperty()
```

Here's you're specifying a weak profile reference on user. It's not required, and if you do populate it, it doesn't have to be a particular model. This lets you optionally store a profile reference without breaking compatibility.

Finally, you could skip the profile altogether and just make your User object [an Expando](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/expandoclass.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are all the applications sharing a database? In that case, you can't store the UserProfile as a field of the User model, as User doesn't always have an associated profile. I would make the User a field of UserProfile and have it point back that way (UserProfile contains a User), and make the `user` field of UserProfile indexed so you can quickly look up the UserProfile for a given user.

If you are just interested in code re-use but not sharing a common database, then you could make those additional fields conditional based on the application. For example:

```
class User(db.Model):
    email = db.EmailProperty()
    password = db.StringProperty()
    role = db.StringProperty(default=roles.USER)
    if APP_HAS_USER_PROFILES:
        first_name = db.StringProperty()
        last_name = db.StringProperty()
        company = db.StringProperty()
```

Then those last three fields will only appear in certain applications. I believe you could also have UserProfile inherit from User, but I'm not sure what happens then (in terms of the database).

Comment: I don't need apps to share any data. This is just a reusable library to quickly implement users functionality in my new applications. The idea is that I want to have an arbitrary number of additional fields and their names for any application. That's why I want define UserProfile model not inside the library, but somewhere in the code of a newly created application.